# Caret dummy variable does not work as expected

Tags: r, caret, dummy-variable

I am trying to use caret's DummyVar function in R to convert some categorical data to numeric. My dataset has an id, town (A or B), district (d1,d2,d3), street(s1,s2,s3,s4), family(f1,f2,f3), gender(male, female), replicate (numeric). Here is a snapshot:
[Dataset Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxM8h.png)

Here is the code I currently have to decode the variables

```
library('caret')
train <- read.csv("HW1PB4Data_train.csv", header = TRUE)
dummy <- dummyVars("~ .", data = train)
train2 <- data.frame(predict(dummy, newdata = train))
train2
```

When I look at the output, train2, it has created a few additional towns (C,D,E) which did not exists in the original data. This does not happen with any of the other columns. Why is this? How do I fix it? Here is a snapshot of the output data: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqi7g.png)

Comment: please provide code for your data, never share data as pictures. You may use `dput(train)`

Comment: Greetings! Both answers have simulated data to help answer your question. In the future it is much more recommended to use the `dput` of your data in your question as advised above :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyr::pivot_wider` or `fastDummies::dummy_cols`

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(subject = c(1.2, 1.5), town = c('a', 'b'), street = c('1', '2'))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  subject town  street
    <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1     1.2 a     1     
2     1.5 b     2
```

Solution with `tidyr`:

```
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from= c(town:street),
                   values_from = c(town:street),
                   values_fill = 0,
                   values_fn = ~1)

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  subject town_a_1 town_b_2 street_a_1 street_b_2
    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1.2        1        0          1          0
2     1.5        0        1          0          1
```

solution with `dummy_cols`:

```
> dummy_cols(df,
             c("town", "street"),
             remove_selected_columns = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  subject town_a town_b street_1 street_2
    <dbl>  <int>  <int>    <int>    <int>
1     1.2      1      0        1        0
2     1.5      0      1        0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is already good. You can also go the easy way and just use an `ifelse` statement to convert your data from categorical to numeric. An example dataset similar to yours:

```
train <- data.frame(subject = round(rnorm(n=100,
                                    mean=5,
                                    sd=2)), # rounded subjects
                    town = rep(c("A","B"),50),
                    district = rep(c("d1","d2"),50),
                    street = rep(c("s1","s2"),50),
                    family = rep(c("f1","f2"),50),
                    gender = rep(c("male","female"),50),
                    replicate = rbinom(n=100,
                                       size=2,
                                       prob=.9))
head(train)
```

Seen below:

```
  subject town district street family gender replicate
1       6    A       d1     s1     f1   male         2
2       4    B       d2     s2     f2 female         2
3       4    A       d1     s1     f1   male         1
4       7    B       d2     s2     f2 female         2
5       3    A       d1     s1     f1   male         2
6       6    B       d2     s2     f2 female         2
```

Simply mutate the gender data with `ifelse` by coding "male" as 0 and everything else ("female" in this case) as 1:

```
m.train <- train %>% 
  mutate(gender = ifelse(gender=="male",0,1))
head(m.train)
```

You get a transformed gender variable with 0's and 1's for dummy coding:

```
  subject town district street family gender replicate
1       6    A       d1     s1     f1      0         2
2       4    B       d2     s2     f2      1         2
3       4    A       d1     s1     f1      0         1
4       7    B       d2     s2     f2      1         2
5       3    A       d1     s1     f1      0         2
6       6    B       d2     s2     f2      1         2
```